# StackOverflow em System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: c#, .net

Olá. 
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação desktop em C# que executa uma rotina da Porta Serial (Escrita, Leitura, Captura de Informações, Exibição destas informações).
Porém, tem horas que aparece um erro de Stack Overflow, mas cada hora é em uma linha diferente

Erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Peguei boa parte dele ja desenvolvido por uma outra pessoa que trabalhava aqui na empresa.

Segue Código completo no link:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Hip8mTZbjIljme6Q0e60XVUEcc1YUnLrwWgpR0LaG_w/pub

Comment: Como está o código? É possível colocá-lo na pergunta?

Comment: Sim. Vou organizar e colocá-lo.

Comment: @EduardoMatheus só com este trecho não para para saber, o problema pode estar estourando aí mas foi causado por outro trecho. Em que linha o erro é apontado?

Comment: coloquei mais uma parte do código.

Comment: Colocar trechos aleatórios não vai ajudar.

Comment: coloquei no Docs o Código completo.

Comment: @EduardoMatheus adicione o *stack trace* da excepcao a pergunta e junte o código relevante (o código a volta da linha onde o *stack trace* indica que houve excepcao). Da forma como esta e perto de impossível entender (ate porque o código no *link* esta caótico).

Comment: @Daniloloko Obrigado! Resolveu perfeitamente o problema.

Comment: Por favor administradores, considerar reabrir a pergunta para que eu possa colocar a resposta e retirar dos comentarios, pois a questão não estava clara e sim a pergunta era considerada dificil. Grato.

Comment: @Daniloloko reaberta. Juntem por favor mais info na pergunta para ficar mais clara também. Depois eu ou outro mod podemos limpar os comentários aqui se os marcarem como obsoletos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O STAThreadAttribute é essencialmente um requerimento para o Windows executar comunicação com componentes COM. Porem o WindowsForms não utiliza componentes COM.
Por isso, o acesso a portas seriais e outros componentes são necessarios ser adicionado o  **[STAThread]** em seu metodo.

Exemplo:

```
[STAThread] //adicionado
private void buscaSensores()
{
...
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182351(VS.80).aspx) demonstra mais detalhes do uso do mesmo.

> STAThreadAttribute indicates that the COM threading model for the
>   application is single-threaded apartment. This attribute must be
>   present on the entry point of any application that uses Windows Forms;
>   if it is omitted, the Windows components might not work correctly. If
>   the attribute is not present, the application uses the multithreaded
>   apartment model, which is not supported for Windows Forms.

Para mais detalhes: [What does [STAThread] do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361033/what-does-stathread-do)